# modal not sliding from top in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

when you click the log in or sign up button a modal opens up....
the modal slides down from the top in chrome browser....
where as in ie9 browser it just opens up....
how to fix the sliding issue in ie 9 browser...

providing my code below

http://jsfiddle.net/KNPZB/10/embedded/result/

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#myModal').modal({ show: false })
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" style="width: 427px; height: 226px;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="width: 336px;">

        <form method="post" class="navbar-form pull-right" action="http://intra.defie.co/Account/">
              <input class="span2" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" style="width: 263px; margin-top: 19px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><br>
              <input class="span2" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="width: 263px;"><br>
              <button type="submit" class="btn" style="margin-top: 13px; margin-left: 100px;">Sign in</button>
            </form>



      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least a couple issues here in the javascript files you have included.

1. In the `<head>` section, you are including **bootstrap.js** before you have even loaded **jquery**. because it looks like you do not load jquery until the near bottom of the page. 
   bootstrap.js needs to come **after** jquery.
2. You have attempted to load bootstrap.js at the top of the page with an **invalid path**, and then at the bottom of the page you load all the bootstrap javascript files that would be included in bootstrap.js anyway. You only need one approach here: use boostrap.js (placed **after jquery**), or load just the bootstrap plugins you need (again, placed **after jquery**). Do a view source on the bootstrap site to see how they do it. twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
3. Both in the head and near the bottom, you are calling jquery functions before jquery itself has loaded, so if you open your browser console with F12, you will see `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in Chrome, and `SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined` in IE9.
4. Besides all the javascript source file issues, the **bootstrap.css** file also has an invalid path and is not loading.

I suspect that once you address these issues, your page may run with the expected behavior; certainly this would be a good place to start.